# What is meant by "a stop order may trigger another stop order?"

Tags: order-execution, stop-loss

I came across this phrase today in my studies without examples, so I am unclear what the meaning is. This is in the context of stop market orders.

Is it referring to the scenario where, say, some order gets filled in the market, and this filled order in turn triggers one of more stop orders in the order book, which in turn turn into market orders, which in turn may trigger additional stop orders which in turn turn into market orders,.....,and so on? In other words, it seems there is some mutual recursion going on here and you can end up in some (finite) cycle?

Answer (score 3):

If a stop order triggers (let's say a stop sell order) it adds an additional sell order which, if executed, can push the price down which can trigger more stop sell orders.

There is no possibility that it could go on forever, since each step uses up a stop sell order and there are only a finite number of stop sell orders.

Comment: Once the last Stop order is triggered the price will usually recover a little as buyers come in and (from personal experience) the person who sold on the last Stop will be miffed at the poor price they got...

Comment: When you say "an additional *sell order*." Just making sure that the said "sell order" here is just the market sell order (at the quantity of the stop sell order that was just triggered)?

Comment: @student010101 there are also stop limit orders which place limit orders when triggered.